# Android and Hudson problem - INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, hudson, maven

I am trying to setup local CI environment - an Android project, built with Maven and now I want to put it on Hudson. But, there is a problem.

When I execute "mvn clean install" in command line everything goes just fine. On the other hand, Hudson build fails saying "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]". For some reason, certificate that is used to sign my test project is not the same as the one used for signing of my app, which is strange because I haven't changed anything regarding this - default, android debug key store is used.

Anyone? Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. The problem was a typo in pom.xml. This solved the problem with certificates. However, I am facing another problem at the moment, but not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is one doing a debug build and the other a release build?  Your own key will only be used for a release build, there is a default key for debug builds.

Comment: Hmmm... I would say that both of them are doing debug build. "mvn clean install" is the command in both cases.
I hope that is an answer on your question.

Comment: @ezamur I think the two different machines might generate different debug keys.  You can over-ride the debug keystore used (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode)

Comment: Oh, I see I forgot to mention that Hudson is installed on my local machine. It uses everything same as I do for development - same android SDK, same Maven installation... This is experimental setup, that's why it is on my dev notebook.